# Parallel hint in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, optimization, append, hint

I want to use parallel hint in my select query to improve performance. But this select statement contains more than one tables in the from clause. How can we use parallel hint in the select statement.

```
INSERT INTO /*+APPEND */ ITEM
    (
    )
    
    SELECT a FROM GTT_LINE p, GTT_LINE_XY r
    Where <condition>
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT a FROM GTT_LINE p, GTT_LINE_XY r
    Where <condition>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let's say your `PARALLEL_MAX_SERVERS` value is 80. Then you can use it:

```
INSERT INTO /*+APPEND */ ITEM
    (
    )
    
    SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(p, 8) PARALLEL(r, 16) */ a 
    FROM GTT_LINE p, GTT_LINE_XY r
    Where <condition>
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(p, 8) PARALLEL(r, 16) */ a 
    FROM GTT_LINE p, GTT_LINE_XY r
    Where <condition>
```

Note: `8` and `16` in sum shouldn't exceed the maximum value of `80`.
To check the maximum value you have to log-in as SYS or SYSDBA and run the next command:

```
SELECT name, value FROM v$parameter WHERE name IN ('parallel_max_servers', 'parallel_execution_enabled');
```

Comment: Thank you. I will check in my code. I hope parallel hint in select statement will improve performance.

Comment: @Ram, you're welcome! It depends. It also can decrease it... the very first suggestion is to use value from `2` to `5` and then increase it. I used to use `10` or `20`)

Comment: This is incorrect. Oracle doesn't add up the DOPs of the various tables like this. It takes the highest DOP of any object used in the execution plan (table or index), or hint if present and uses that for every operation that is to be parallelized, which in your example would mean BOTH tables will get a DOP of 16. Furthermore, you don't need to be SYS in order to view v$parameter. You just need the SELECT ANY DICTIONARY priv which is very commonly given to developers.

Comment: @PaulW, good to know the first one part, but not the other.

Comment: See my answer for further details

Comment: @PaulW, `commonly given priv` isn't so. It depends. And that hint has many options, which you've skiped.

Comment: Aksen, the whole point of my comment and my answer below is that the older form of the parallel hint, wherein you list the row source alias, is LESS desirable because you have to keep repeating it for every table you want parallelized, and yet it does no good. I don't think you understand that Oracle will IGNORE that differences in the degree or parallelism from table to table. It will simply use the highest one for all of them, no matter what you put in your hints. So using that older form requires much more typing and produces nothing of advantage. It's far better to omit the alias entirely.

Comment: If you have a query with 20 tables, do you want to say PARALLEL(table1,8) PARALLE(table2,8), etc... 20 times, in perhaps a dozen different query blocks? Or is it not better to have only one PARALLEL(8) for the entire query? Take your pick. Your question asked how to get parallelism applied to multiple tables, and my answer provides by far the best way to do that... simply omit the table alias and the parallel hint will automatically apply to every table.

Comment: "commonly given priv isn't so. It depends." - I've been a DBA for decades, and have seen no pressing reason to be overly stingy with the SELECT ANY DICTIONARY priv when developers have a legit need for it. There's nothing exposed but metadata and structure, no data. Further, if your DBA won't grant you that, you sure aren't going to get SYSDBA privs!!!! So, what's a better way to see v$parameter? Unless you are the DBA you have no choice but to get SELECT ANY DICTIONARY because no developer is going to get SYSDBA unless it's their private database on their workstation.

Comment: is it possible to use parallel hint without table name.is it makes any difference? I used PARALLEL(p, 5) PARALLEL(r, 5)  in the above select statement using GTT table. currently I am using multithreading in plsql. I ran the package contains this select statement. It is not running.

Comment: i exit from oracle and tried to reconnect, but it is showing maximum number of session exceeded.

Comment: @Ram, it's another question and there you have to provide completely different system info. You can find all options that can receive this hint. If you have an alias of the table, then this alias should be used as an argument.

Comment: @PaulW, good for you, the reward for your DBA highness is a donut)

Answer (score 1):

Prior to 11g, you had to provide a hint for every table you wanted parallelism for. Since 11g, you can omit the table alias and a single parallel hint applies to the whole statement. Oracle will decide for itself what is to be parallelized and what not, and typically it will tend to parallelize most everything. The degree specified will be used for all objects where possible. It's simply:

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND PARALLEL(16) */ INTO ITEM
    (
    )
    SELECT a 
    FROM GTT_LINE p, GTT_LINE_XY r
    Where <condition>
    UNION
    SELECT a 
    FROM GTT_LINE p, GTT_LINE_XY r
    Where <condition>
```

Keep in mind that the parallel hint will apply to the select portion, not the insert because that would require enabling parallel dml (`ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML` or the hint `enable_parallel_dml`). So to parallelize the whole thing including the block loading step of the insert, you need:

```
INSERT /*+ APPEND PARALLEL(16) enable_parallel_dml */ INTO ITEM
    (
    )
    SELECT a 
    FROM GTT_LINE p, GTT_LINE_XY r
    Where <condition>
    UNION
    SELECT a 
    FROM GTT_LINE p, GTT_LINE_XY r
    Where <condition>
```

Lastly, note that I shifted your hint one word back, to right after the keyword `INSERT`. Oracle only looks for hints immediately following the initial keyword of a SQL block.

With regard to choosing a DOP (degree of parallelism, 16 in this case), you have several factors to consider:

```
 1. What is the parallel_max_servers
 2. Is parallel_degree_policy = manual or auto?
 3. If auto, what is parallel_degree_limit set to?
 4. Has the DBA overridden hints with optimizer_ignore_parallel_hints?
 5. How many CPU cores are on the host(s) the database is mounted on?
 6. How many others sessions might be using how many parallel slaves at the same time?
 7. Is there a DBRM (Resource Manager) rule defined that caps DOP for your consumer group?
 8. How big are the tables you are scanning or joining?
```

Because of the complexity of all this, it is best to simply ask your DBA what is recommended for this system. If you use too much, you can cause problems for the database. I recommend starting out with 4 and only increasing if needed, assuming sufficient resources. Numbers of 8 and 16 are not special, they're just conventional among programmers.